# Signed and RequireAdministrator executable being run from temp folder?

Tags: windows, uac, elevation, windows-appcompat-platform

i manifested my executable as require administrator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 

    <!-- Disable Windows Vista UAC compatability heuristics -->
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo> 
</assembly>
```

And then i digitally signed it.

But then when i run the executable i noticed something odd: the name of the executable on the **Consent** dialog changed from `PingWarning.exe` to `pinxxxx.tmp`; as though a temp copy was made, and that is being run:

[image]

i dug out Process Montior, to see if anyone is creating a ***.tmp** file when i launch my executable, and there is:

[image]

The **Application Information** service inside this particular `svchost` container is **intentionally** copying my executable to the Windows temp folder, and asking for user "Consent" from there; giving an invalid filename.

Once consent has been granted, the executable is run from its original location:
[image: link text]

The file is not copied to the temp folder if i do not digitally sign it:

[image]

---

So my problem is the *invalid filename* appearing on the **consent** dialog when i *digitally sign* my executable which has been manifested as `requireAdministrator`.

What do?

---

**Update:**

The closest thing to an explanation i can find comes from [Uninformed.org](http://uninformed.org/index.cgi?v=8&a=6&p=3) :

> ### Breaking the Broker
>
> In the case of a launch request for a
>   program requesting uiaccess,
>   *appinfo!RAiLaunchAdminProcess* is
>   called to service the request. The
>   process is then verified to be within
>   the (hardcoded) set of allowed
>   directories by
>   *appinfo!AiCheckSecureApplicationDirectory*.
>   After validating that the program is
>   being launched from within an allowed
>   directory, control is eventually
>   passed to *appinfo!AiLaunchProcess*
>   which performs the remaining work
>   necessary to service the launch
>   request. At this point, due to the
>   "secure" application directory
>   requirement, it is not possible for a
>   limited user (or a user running with
>   low integrity, for that matter) to
>   place a custom executable in any of
>   the "secure" application directories.

The hint being that are some (undocumented, unspecified) hardcoded paths that an application is "allowed" to be located in.

The other is is **for a program requesting uiaccess**. In my case i did not have `uiAccess="false"` in my original manifest. But changing the manifest to include the no ui access:

But that did not fix the original problem.

---

**Update Two:**

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sas/nf-sas-sendsas):

> ### SendSAS function
>
> **Important**  Applications with the **uiAccess** flag set to true must be
>   **Authenticode** signed to start properly. In addition, the application must reside in a protected location in the
>   file system. Currently, there are the two allowable protected locations:
>
> - **\Program Files**
> - **\windows\system32**

This seems to backup the notion that an executable requesting `uiAccess` must be in an allowed location; except i'm not asking for uiAccess.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the same problem with unsigned applications, specifically with NSIS and InnoSetup installers (A bit of a problem when 1gb+ installers are copied to %windir%\temp and then scanned by consent.exe)

The NSIS bug tracker has a [entry](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2785629&group_id=22049&atid=373085) about it. Back when I was investigating this, I was in contact with someone @ MS and they were supposed to contact someone that worked on UAC but nothing really came of it. The only applicable information I got from that conversation was this quote:

> One friend in Windows had a vague recollection that this may have been a 
>   mitigation for a concern about file tampering while the trust dialog was being 
>   displayed